# How to bind same key action to buttons in different windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, frame, key-bindings

I have been searching a lot and I still don't know, what is the problem. I have two windows asking for some values and as a result different functions are executed. I tried to bind an "Enter" key to buttons of different windows (so different functions should be executed), but this doesn't work.

Only thing that i could do is to bind key to the whole Frame, then unbind it and bind one more time. It works, but i'm curious why i can't link "Enter" key to separate buttons while no error appear. Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk              

class Page(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.shared_data = {
            "number_of_frequencies": tk.StringVar(),
            "frequencies": []}

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid()
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def create_entry_widget(self, i):
        self.number = tk.StringVar()
        self.number.set('')
        self.shared_data["frequencies"].append(self.number)
        new_widget = tk.Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.number)
        return new_widget

    def show_frame(self, c):
        for frame in self.frames.values():
            frame.grid_remove()
        frame = self.frames[c]
        frame.grid()
        global number_of_frequencies
        try:
            number_of_frequencies = int(self.shared_data["number_of_frequencies"].get())
            for i in range(number_of_frequencies):
                tk.Label(self.master, text="Frequency "+str(i+1)).grid(row=i, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
                self.entry_widgets = self.create_entry_widget(i)
                self.entry_widgets.grid(row=i, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

            page1 = self.get_page(PageOne)

            tk.Button(self, text="Exit",
                      command=lambda: self.quitALL()).grid(row=i+1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

            self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "     Done     ", 
                      command=lambda: [page1.enter_freqs(), self.quitALL()])

            self.unbind_all('<Return>') # work
            self.bind('<Return>', (lambda a: [page1.enter_freqs(), self.quitALL()])) # work

#            self.button1.bind('<Return>', (lambda a: [page1.enter_freqs(), self.quitALL()])) #doesn't work

            self.button1.grid(row=i+1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

            frame.tkraise()
        except:
            frame.tkraise()

    def get_page(self, page_class):
        return self.frames[page_class]

    def quitALL(self):
        self.destroy()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller=controller

        self.text = tk.Text(self, bg='gray93', bd=0, height=1, width=30, font=('Helvetica', 14))
        self.text.insert(tk.INSERT, "Please enter number of frequencies:")
        self.text.grid(padx=10, pady=10)

        entry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["number_of_frequencies"])
        entry.grid(padx=10)

        self.controller.bind('<Return>', (lambda a: controller.show_frame(PageOne))) # work

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="     Done     ",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
#        self.button.bind('<Return>', (lambda a: controller.show_frame(PageOne))) # doesn't work

        self.button.grid(padx=10, pady=10) 


class PageOne(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller=controller
        self.freq_list = self.controller.shared_data["frequencies"]
        self.freq_list_int = []

    def enter_freqs(self):
        for freq in self.freq_list:
            self.freq_list_int.append(int(freq.get()))
        self.func(self.freq_list_int)

    def func(self, freq_list):
        print('some stuff')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Page()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `self.button1` is storing the return value from grid method, which is None. That's why you can't bind any event with that button.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you! I corrected my code, but it didn't help.

Comment: Your updated code worked for me. I commented your `#work` lines and uncommented `#doesn't work` lines and it seems to be working. I could even add extra print in these bind calls to confirm. What problem are you facing now?

Comment: Hmmm, it's strange, because when i comment #work lines, uncomment #doesn't work lines and run the program, happens nothing on pressing "Enter" key: no error, no message, just nothing happens

Comment: Ok, just to confirm, you want to call your function when pressing 'Enter' where? When you bind 'Enter' on button widget, then your context should be on the button(you can change by pressing TAB key) and then pressing 'Enter' will call the function. Do you want to call your function when pressed 'Enter' while you are typing the value in Entry objects?

Comment: I want to call my functions (by pressing "Enter") after entering values. For the first window this would cause switching to the next window (where i would use entered value) and for the second - calling function "func", but after user has entered all necessary values.

Comment: Then you should bind 'Enter' on your Entry widgets. You can validate the values at the start of function and proceed only if valid values found. If values not found, then just return, user can press 'Enter' again after providing values. You can even keep a label to show such error when user tries to proceed without typing values.

Comment: Thanks, it's good idea! i'll change my code accordingly your advice. But i still don't understand why i can't bind "Enter" to buttons in different windows.

Comment: Actually you can. Like I said, they are binded. But if your cursor is in the Entry widget and you press 'Enter' there, it will not check for binding of Button widget. To do that your context should be on the Button. After typing value, press TAB key a few times until you can see your button highlighted and then press 'Enter' to call the function binded to Button.

Comment: Now i get it. Thank you for your help!